# Load a class with arguments within the same project

Tags: java

Alright, i'm trying to Xbootclasspath a jar from within my project. Currently I have to load my application through command-line with the follow command:

```
java -Xbootclasspath/p:canvas.jar -jar application.jar
```

This works perfectly fine but I want to do this without having to enter command line, is there I way I can Xbootclasspath from within the jar?

Thanks.

Comment: Why not simply creating a shell script/.bat file?

Comment: Personally i think that's unacceptable for the users.

Comment: I haven't really had any experience with it but maybe you could do something with [Launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/index.html)?

Comment: Whats the purpose of using XBootclasspath? Are you overriding some Java builtin class?

Comment: Be careful about the issues raised here with violating the license: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8310083/java-cvm-boot-class-path

Comment: @GyroGearless Yes, i'm using my own Canvas instead of using the one of an applet i'm loading.

Comment: @user2639767 RuneScape, eh? I've written a program that does the same thing, and I've answered the question using a stripped version of my solution to this same issue. I intend to open-source my program, (RuneDream, you may have heard of it), sometime soon, so you can refer to that once it's up for the complete version of my `Boot` class.  I'll add the link to my answer once I upload the project somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most clear solution is to have **two** main classes.

Your first class, named `Boot` or similar, will be the outside entry point into the application, as set in the jar's manifest.  This class will form the necessary runtime command to start your actual main class (named `Application` or similar), with the Xboot parameter.

```
public class Boot {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String location = Boot.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath();
        location = URLDecoder.decode(location, "UTF-8").replaceAll("\\\\", "/");
        String app = Application.class.getCanonicalName();
        String flags = "-Xbootclasspath/p:canvas.jar";
        boolean windows = System.getProperty("os.name").contains("Win");

        StringBuilder command = new StringBuilder(64);
        if (windows) {
            command.append("javaw");
        } else {
            command.append("java");
        }
        command.append(' ').append(flags).append(' ');
        command.append('"').append(location).append('"');
        // append any necessary external libraries here
        for (String arg : args) {
             command.append(' ').append('"').append(arg).append('"');
        }

        Process application = null;
        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        if (windows) {
            application = runtime.exec(command.toString());
        } else {
            application = runtime.exec(new String[]{ "/bin/sh", "-c", command.toString() });
        }

        // wire command line output to Boot to output it correctly
        BufferedReader strerr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(application.getErrorStream()));
        BufferedReader strin = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(application.getInputStream()));
        while (isRunning(application)) {
            String err = null;
            while ((err = strerr.readLine()) != null) {
                System.err.println(err);
            }
            String in = null;
            while ((in = strin.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(in);
            }
            try {
                Thread.sleep(50);
            } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {
            }
        }
    }

    private static boolean isRunning(Process process) {
        try {
            process.exitValue();
        } catch (IllegalThreadStateException e) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

And your `Application` class runs your actual program:

```
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // display user-interface, etc
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks finn, this helped me out!

Answer (score 0):

Feels yucky, but could you do a Runtime.exec that calls to java with the provided options and a new parameter (along with some conditional code that looks for that) to prevent a recursive loop of spawning new processes?